# What is the purpose of group "wheel" on FreeBSD (FreeNAS) OS?

Tags: freebsd, freenas

I am setting up a new server based on [FreeNAS](https://www.freenas.org/), a FreeBSD-based operating system. The system has a group, `wheel`. I have a vague idea that sysadmins should be added to group `wheel`, and that the group confers ability to use `su` (superuser). However, I can't find this written down anywhere.

What is the purpose of group `wheel`? Under what circumstances I should add my users to it? Please also cite FreeBSD documentation which explains this.

Comment: @Kusalananda thank you for your attention to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add users to the `wheel` group if they need to use the `su` command to become root.

As you are using a FreeNAS system, you may want to look at the documentation regarding [the Groups interface](https://www.ixsystems.com/documentation/freenas/11.2-U5/accounts.html#groups) where it says, regarding the Primary Group drop-down menu,

> Unset New Primary Group to access this menu. For security reasons, FreeBSD will not give a user su permissions if wheel is their primary group. To give a user su access, add them to the wheel group in Auxiliary groups.

For more documentation regarding `wheel` on FreeBSD, see e.g.

- [section 10.4 of the FreeBSD FAQ](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/faq/admin.html#idp49238264): "Why do I get the error, you are not in the correct group to su root when I try to su to root?"

  > This is a security feature. In order to su to root, or any other account with superuser privileges, the user account must be a member of the wheel group. If this feature were not there, anybody with an account on a system who also found out root's password would be able to gain superuser level access to the system.
- [section 3.3.1.3 of the FreeBSD Handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/users-synopsis.html): The Superuser Account

  > There are several ways to gain superuser privilege. While one can log in as root, this is highly discouraged.
  >
  > Instead, use su(1) to become the superuser. If - is specified when running this command, the user will also inherit the root user's environment. The user running this command must be in the wheel group or else the command will fail. The user must also know the password for the root user account.
- [section 3.3.2.1 of the FreeBSD Handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/users-synopsis.html): `adduser`

  > [...] In this example, the user has been invited into the wheel group, allowing them to become the superuser with su(1).

And obviously the manual for `su(1)` as well.

Comment: Excellent references, thank you. I find it interesting that all of these are explanations of superuser, describing the "wheel" group in passing. None are part of a listing of system-defined groups, which describe the purpose of the "wheel" group itself.

Comment: @JimDeLaHunt There is a [glossary of terms](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/freebsd-glossary.html) in the Handbook, but the `wheel` group is not mentioned there. It is maybe in itself "unimportant" while documenting the action of switching to root with `su` is more important (and then mentioning the prerequisite of membership in that group, as you say, in passing).

Comment: it's a matter of context and task. When my task is to create a user in the FreeNAS WebGUI, it asks me if I want to include the user in groups "wheel", "staff", and several others. In that context, nothing is mentioning superuser. In that context, for that task, "wheel" group's purpose and use is important.

Comment: @JimDeLaHunt Also found this documented by FreeNAS (see updated answer).

Answer (score 4):

It's in the [`su(1)` man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?su(1)).

```
PAM is used to set  the policy su(1) will use.  In particular, by default
only users  in the "wheel" group can switch to UID 0 ("root").  This group
requirement may be  changed by modifying the "pam_group" section of
 /etc/pam.d/su.  See pam_group(8) for details on how to modify this set-
ting.
```

A very ancient version of the man page [said](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=su&manpath=FreeBSD%202.2.8-RELEASE):

```
Only users  who are a member of group 0 (normally "wheel") can su to
"root".   If group  0 is missing or empty, any user can su to "root".
```

This allows you to control which users can `su`. It is not likely that you want *every single user* of your system to be able to `su`.